# Failed to get D-BUS connection (systemctl, pulse) after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, pulseaudio, 15.04, dbus, systemd

I upgraded to 15.04 and I seem to have issue with permissions talking to D-BUS. Pulseaudio is completely broken (no sound, no volume controls), and systemctl (and also `sudo systemctl`) reports:

```
 $ systemctl status   # with sudo or without
 Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

I googled around and saw no clear answer or a way to find out what is happening... Any hint?

**EDIT:** everything works when booting with upstart.

Comment: I've fixed this issue by installing systemd-sysv package.

Comment: Thx, @spektom, for me the issue resolved somehow "automatically", and I see now systemd-sysv is isntalled. It might have been that. Could you post as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `systemd-sysv` package fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround add

export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/`id -u`

into your environment, for example in .bashrc

Refs:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+question/287454
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423632/systemctl-user-not-available-for-www-data-user